# Best practices on making c++ class "Showable" (string, ostream)

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a value-semantic class that I'd like to be "showable" in the same sense as Haskells `Show` class, or Python provides a universal `__str__()` function.

In c++:

- I could overload `operator<<(ostream&, ...)` so I can output my class to e.g. `cout`
- I could overload `operator std::string()` so my class converts to *std::string*
- I could overload `operator const char*()` so my class converts to *const char* *.
- I could write a `str()` member, or a `to_string(...)` free function

**Each of these functions could be defined in terms of the other.** Is one option better over the others? Are these all the options? What would the most elegant way be to do this given c++11/14/17?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is going to be put in hold in a very few minutes, but I will still share my thoughts here.

First, of all, we can remove const char* / std::string() operator overloads from the list. If the class is not a string, it should not be convertible to string, and serialization enablement does not make your class a string.

As for `str()`, `to_string` and `operator <<` they a pretty equivalent. However, since for any complex class to_string() and str() are very likely to use ostreams internally, I believe, `operator <<` is the best option.

Comment: Yes, I was afraid the question was too open, but dared anyway. What is your reason for `str()` and `to_string()` to use `operator<<` internally and not the other way around?

Comment: Ah, I guess you mean preference over e.g. stringstream above manual string concatenation. In which case your choice for `operator<<` makes sense.

Comment: @StijnFrishert, exactly. It is hard to serialize a complex class with simple string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether it's best practice or not but...

1. for debugging I always define `operator<<` which gives a summarised output in text form (this means it's easy to stream objects to log files)
2. for formatted output I would probably choose to implement this in terms of free functions: `detail::x_detail_writer write_details(const X&)` and then give `detail::x_detail_writer` (which is a functor) an `operator<< overload`
3. for anything but the most trivial object I implement `to_string` in terms of `operator<<` if at all.

for aiding with debugging output we have a helper class which goes something like this:

```
template<class T>
struct make_writeable {
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& t) {
    // example prefix...
    os << demangle(typeid(T).name()) << "{";
    t.write(os);
    // example postfix:
    os << " }";
    return os;
  }
};
```

then derive some class from this and give it a member function called write:

```
struct X : make_writeable<X>
{
  void write(std::ostream& os) const {
    // write out members here. they will appear within the prefix and postfix
  }
};
```

Comment: Good mention there's sometimes more ways than one to print an object (debug info, formatted output, ...). Seems another argument against conversion operators ('cause what output format do you want, then?).